# How to replace multiple characters at once in emacs

Tags: emacs, replace, elisp

What is the quickest way to replace multiple characters at once in emacs?  For instance I would like to act on the region and replace 1 with a, 2 with b, ..., 9 with i.

Comment: Too situational to do it with elisp. Perhaps try http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Query.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stitch elisp into regex replacements (not sure if you can do the same with `replace-string`). For instance,

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \([1-9]\) \,(char-to-string (+ 96 \#1))
```

should replace single digits `1-9` with the letters `a-i` as appropriate.

Comment: `(string-to-int \1)` can also be written as just `\#1`.

Comment: Nice idea and enough for my purposes. Thanks.